# Getting User data after succefull login from CAS Server using Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, cas

New to Spring security 3.0 and CAS.
The client web application is a Spring 3.0 mvc which uses the Spring security filter(DelegatingFilterProxy) with CAS to authenticate users and it works fine.
The login link at the top of each page redirects users to the remote CAS server and after successfully logged in the CAS remote server sends back the web page to the Spring web application without any errors.
The problem is, I don't know how to get the user's data from CAS?

security.xml file:

```
<http entry-point-ref="casEntryPoint"  auto-config="true">
          <intercept-url pattern="/*.html" filters="none"/>
          <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" filters="none"/>     
          <custom-filter ref="casFilter" position="CAS_FILTER" />
              <logout logout-success-url="https://CAS_server.com/cas/logout"/>
     </http>  


      <user-service id="userService">
        <user name="myApp_auto" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
       </user-service>

    <authentication-manager alias="authManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="casAuthProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>


  <bean id="serviceProperties"   class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
          <property name="service"   value="https://myIpAddrress/myapps/homePage.htm"/>
          <property name="sendRenew" value="false"/>          

   </bean> 


 <bean id="casEntryPoint"    class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint">
  <property name="loginUrl" value="https://CAS_server.com/cas/login"/>
  <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties"/>
</bean> 

    <bean id="casFilter"      class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
      <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authManager"/>
     <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
       <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/myapps/homePage.html" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    </bean>   

     <bean id="ticketValidator" class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator">
     <constructor-arg value="https://CAS_server.com/cas/login" />            
     </bean>



    <bean id="casAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
     <property name="ticketValidator" ref="ticketValidator"/>
     <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties"/>
      <property name="authenticationUserDetailsService">
           <bean   class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
               <constructor-arg ref="userService" />
           </bean>
         </property> 
         <property name="key" value="empNumber"></property>  
      </bean>
```

Comment: What data are you referring to? Normally the only information CAS transfers to your app is the username. The remainder is loaded locally from the `UserDetailsService` you've configured (which is passed the retrieved username by Spring Security).

Comment: I meant user's employeeId and .., can you explicitly give some codes that use  UserDetailsService.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

During the authentication, the CAS server is generally retrieving the user id but also his attributes. So you could skip doing that on the application side.
The way to send these attributes from the CAS server to the application is to use the SAML service ticket validation after properly configuring your CAS service to allow these attributes to be sent:
`http://jasig.github.io/cas/current/integration/Attribute-Release.html`
`https://github.com/Jasig/java-cas-client/blob/master/cas-client-core/src/main/java/org/jasig/cas/client/validation/Saml11TicketValidator.java`